# Eclipse PDT debugging - how to avoid break on first php tag?

Tags: php, debugging, eclipse-pdt

I have recently setup my Eclipse PDT environment. All fine, only one disturbing feature: Whenever I debug my code, debugger not only stops at the first breakpoint, but also at the first `<?php` tag. So I need to always press `F8` to continue.

Any way to avoid this initial break? I just want to stop at breakpoints only.

[image: PHP breakpoint]

Screenshot to show what I mean, initial stop at `<?php` even with no breakpoint set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "Debug Configurations" select the configuration that you are using. You should see a section "Breakpoint". Uncheck "Break at first line". Save and try again.